# How can I listen to an event and call an api

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Do you know any documentation about listening to an event (for example https://sap.github.io/spartacus/classes/ProductDetailsPageEvent.html) and making a call to an api if the event has been triggered? Is that possibile with spartacus?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the documentation for event service is here: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/event-service/